# How can I modify my current activity to support Swipe View?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, swipe

So this is what my current activity looks like:

```
package com.example;

import com.google.analytics.tracking.android.EasyTracker;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class TestActivity extends Activity{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.test_layout);

        // Look up the AdView as a resource and load a request.
        AdView adView = (AdView)this.findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        adView.loadAd(adRequest);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        EasyTracker.getInstance(this).activityStart(this); // Add this method.
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        EasyTracker.getInstance(this).activityStop(this); // Add this method.
    }
}
```

I would like to add a page that consists of a single webview. I want the user to be able to swipe from this activity to that activity (the one with the webview). I'm having a lot of problems figuring out how to implement the swipeviews. Can anyone please help me? Thank you!

Comment: Did you check out this [link](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html)?

Comment: @Octopus Yes, but I'm having difficulties comprehending it.

Comment: Ok, then, you have to put the specifics of the difficulties you face in your post. It will help you to get answers